# Schedule refresh in SQL

Tags: sql-server, refresh

I want to connect power bi to SQL server. I have to refresh SQL query every 2 days and I don't want to schedule power bi.
what is the appropriate query in SQL server for this?
I searched some phrases such as "how to schedule refresh query in SQL" in Google. But I couldn't find a clear answer.
please help me

Comment: first create a materialized view with query then create a job schedule where you refresh materialized view as per your requirement.

Comment: You don't "refresh" a materialised view, @RahulBiswas . The view would automatically reflect the changes in the underlying tables, as at the end of the day it's a pseudo table defined by a `SELECT` statement.

Comment: view will automatically refreshed but materialized view need refreshed otherwise current changes will not reflected.

Comment: @RahulBiswas Nope - a view - materialized or otherwise - never needs to be "refreshed". Whenever you select rows from a view, the resultset will always contain current information from the underlying tables. A materialized view is automatically maintained by the database engine whenever the underlying tables are changed.

Comment: Define exactly what you mean by "refresh". Are you changing the definition of the query? Are you displaying or storing the resultset from your query somewhere?

Answer (score 1):

You can either have a job in the application that will run the procedure periodically (I don't recommend it) or use a job in the SQL server.
More info about it here - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ssms/agent/create-a-job?view=sql-server-ver15

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

what are you looking is called Job in SQL Server. it is very helpful in repetitive tasks such as executing store procedures and so on. it act like Macro Recorders.